# Go pointer to array

Tags: go, pointers

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    b := [32]byte{}
    var p *[32]byte
    p = &b
    zero(p)
}

func zero(ptr *[32]byte) {
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", ptr)
    for i, _ := range ptr {
        fmt.Printf("%p", ptr[i])
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v", *ptr)
}
```

`*ptr` is containing the whole array, `ptr` is containing the address of the array elements. Is that right?

Why is that `ptr[i]` is not giving any address of the array element.
but `&ptr[i]` is giving the address..

Go's pointer is completely different from C's Pointer?

Comment: Given `var ptr *[32]byte` then `ptr` is a pointer to an array. The expression `*ptr` dereferences the pointer and the result of that expression is the array itself. The `ptr[i]` expression is shorthand for `(*ptr)[i]`. So `(*ptr)[i]` first dereferences the pointer to get the array and then with the index expression `[i]` retrieves the array's element at the index `i`.

Comment: Because that's how the language works.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks for the detailed answer. I understood that. I knew `int *p` and the arithmetic of pointers in C.. I think the concept is completely differenct from C. Everyone told that Go is similar to C. It is not!

Comment: @agriz in many ways Go is quite *similar* to C, especially if you add other languages to the comparison, then you'll find that Go can be *more* similar to C than other languages. However "similar" does not mean "same", so when everyone is telling you "Go is similar to C" you should not expect to be able to do things in Go the "same" way you can do them in C.

Comment: @mkopriva Yes... You are absolutely right. Thank you so much for the answer.. I actually am not using C after collage. Almost forgot it. But i have to go through the basics of GO lang from the docs to understand it completley. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

@mkopriva

Thanks for the answer. It might help others.

```
p = &b
```

From the question, it does not assign the address of first element of the array. In technical, it does assign the first address. But `p` is pointing to the whole array.

So dereferening the variable `ptr`, we get the array itself.

From **@mkopriva** comment...

> Given var ptr *[32]byte then ptr is a pointer to an array. The
> expression *ptr dereferences the pointer and the result of that
> expression is the array itself. The ptr[i] expression is shorthand for
> (*ptr)[i]. So (*ptr)[i] first dereferences the pointer to get the
> array and then with the index expression [i] retrieves the array's
> element at the index i